# can't update data in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

i have 2 database : 
1. users (name, username, password, remember_token, admin)
2. dosen (iddosen, user_id, namadosen, nipy, etc)

i want to update data but when i click save it's not updated to database. there's no error when i click save.

in edit view i use relationship
    {!! Form::model($user->dosen, ['route' => ['admin.dosen.update', $user->dosen->user_id], 'method' => 'PUT']) !!}

this is my method :

```
public function update($id)
{
    $userUpdate = Request::all();
    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->update($userUpdate);
    return redirect('admin/dosen')->with('message', 'Data berhasil diubah!');
}
```

Edit view:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Edit {{ $user->dosen->namadosen }}</div>

            <div class="panel-body">
                <!-- jika terjadi error, akan menampilkan pesan -->
                        @if ($errors->any())
                            <ul class="alert alert-danger">
                            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                            @endforeach
                            </ul>
                        @endif

                        {!! Form::model($user->dosen, ['route' => ['admin.dosen.update', $user->dosen->user_id], 'method' => 'PUT']) !!}

                            <div class="form-group">
                                {!! Form::label('iddosen', 'Kode Dosen') !!}
                                {!! Form::text('iddosen', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'readonly' => 'true']) !!}
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                {!! Form::label('nipy', 'NIPY') !!}<br>
                                {!! Form::text('nipy', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                {!! Form::label('namadosen', 'Nama Dosen') !!}
                                {!! Form::text('namadosen', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                {!! Form::label('alamatdosen', 'Alamat') !!}
                                {!! Form::textarea('alamatdosen', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                            </div>

                             <div class="form-group">
                                {!! Form::label('notelpdosen', 'No HP Dosen') !!}
                                {!! Form::text('notelpdosen', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                            </div>

                             <div class="form-group">
                                {!! Form::label('tempatlahirdosen', 'Tempat & Tanggal Lahir') !!}
                                <div class="form-inline">
                                {!! Form::text('tempatlahirdosen', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                                {!! Form::text('tanggallahirdosen', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                            </div>
                            </div>



                            {{ Form::button('<i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> Simpan', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary'] )  }}
                            <a class="btn btn-small btn-success" href="{{ URL('dosen/') }}"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i> Kembali</a>

                        {!! Form::close() !!}

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: can you show your User model ?

Comment: @jaysingkar User model : `public function dosen()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Dosen');
}`

dosen model : `public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}`

Comment: what is the primary key for user tbale? `id`. right ?

Comment: @jaysingkar yes "id". and primary key for dosen is "iddosen"

Comment: I think you are getting dosen data in your method instead of user. Could you confirm if `Request::all()` is having the columns you want to update ?

Comment: also could you add your route from `Routes.php` which is handling this request ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the form it looks like you want to update the `dosen` table, not the `user` one. You have to explicitly do that. `$user->update()` will only update your `name, username, password` fields.

So rather return the relation and then update it.

```
public function update($id)
{
    $dosenUpdate = Request::all();
    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->dosen()->update($dosenUpdate);
    return redirect('admin/dosen')->with('message', 'Data berhasil diubah!');
}
```

Comment: got error `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '_method' in 'field list' (SQL: update `dosen` set `_method` = PUT, `_token` = QWFo70aZUrny3RyPJRQyBJiLUGyWxtqjpdVxTaZj, `iddosen` = DSN003, `nipy` = 31351.1351.13, `namadosen` = Dimas Sasongko, S.Kom, `alamatdosen` = Surakartaaaaaa, `notelpdosen` = 856245242, `tempatlahirdosen` = Solo, `tanggallahirdosen` = 1985-04-20, `updated_at` = 2016-08-06 16:04:32 where `dosen`.`user_id` = 74 and `dosen`.`user_id` is not null)`

Comment: Change `$dosenUpdate = $request->all();` to only include the fields in the table you require, like `$dosenUpdate = $request->only(['nipy', 'namadosen', 'alamatdosen']);`.

Comment: Thanks it's working . update : `$dosenUpdate = Request::only(['nipy', 'namadosen', 'alamatdosen']);`

Comment: Great, if the answer solved your issue, you are welcome to select it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing `updated_at` column in user table.
So let try to add `updated_at` column with "DATETIME" datatype and test it again.

You also should check messages in error log file of your application. It is usually configured in your virtual host or it is the default error log file of Apache.

Beside that you should check if you already enabled debug mode in config/app.php to see error messages.

```
'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true),
```

If so, error messages will be stored in storage/logs/laravel.log.